# Open external links in Phonegap Build App (iOS/Android)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I'm using **Phonegap Build** to deploy mi Apps, I'm using the **Cordova 3.3.0** version.

I want open external links in the native browser (**Android/iOS**). I'm trying to use the **InAppBrowser plugin** of Cordova, but it doesn't work for me. Open the links but inside the App without back button... :/

I've seen answers like [Include phonegap.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675861/external-links-in-phonegap-app-do-not-open-well) (but when deploys with Phonegap Build you don't have to include it, PGB do it for you), or using or [using a function to open links + InAppBrowser Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618840/consistent-way-to-open-links-from-phonegap-app-in-both-android-and-ios#_=_), or even who say that this is fixed [deploying locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534630/phonegap-build-how-to-open-external-url-in-device-browser-on-android), but **I can't deploy locally** because my Mac doesn't support the new versions of XCode and iOS SDK's.

This is the relevant code of my **config.xml**:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.3.3" />
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<access origin="*" />
```

This is the **JS function** I've been trying:

```
function abrirURL(url){
    if(device.platform === 'Android') {
        navigator.app.loadUrl(url, {openExternal:true});
    } else {
        window.open(url, '_system');
    }
}
```

And the **links** I tried, from the most basic to the use of functions:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
<a href="#" onClick="abrirURL('http://www.example.com');">Link</a>
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank');">
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.example.com', '_system');">
```

Nothing of this works for me, somebody help me please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my problem was [include phonegap.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675861/external-links-in-phonegap-app-do-not-open-well/18697241#18697241) to my `<head>` in all the pages where I will use the InAppBrowser: `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>`

I'm gonna explain a little, why this solution in first time doesn't seem logic to me (and maybe you too), but then I tried and it works.

This is what Phonegap in his [plugin documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html#importing-native) section says:

> "If a plugin utilizes the `js-module` element to direct cordova to load the plugin javascripts, then no `<script>` references will be necessary to load a plugin. **This is the case for the core cordova plugins**"

[InAppBrowser](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/658) is a core cordova plugin. But for some strange reason don't work until you include the `phonegap.js` file (at least in 0.3.3 version).

**NOTE**: I found a bug. Some people says that you have to include 3 files: `phonegap.js`, `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugins.js`. But when I include this 3 files my app works fine in iOS 7, but in iOS 6 ignore the use of the plugin (Using: Cordova 3.3.0 + Phonegap Build + InAppBrowser 0.3.3).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do two things to get this to work in 3.7.0.

config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

In HTML a tags

```
<a onclick="window.open(this.href,'_system','location=no');return false;" href="http://stackoverflow.com">
```

I actually wrote a function to handle this so my HTML would be normal

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('target') === '_blank') {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'),'_system','location=no');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```